# Spring + Quartz - Trigger repeat interval exception

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz in my spring boot application.
I need to set a trigger that will fire as soon as it is created and then every 30 days.

So, i create my jobDetail

```
JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        jobDetailFactoryBean.setJobClass(CheckContract.class);
        jobDetailFactoryBean.setName("JobDetail" + contract.getContractId());
        jobDetailFactoryBean.setGroup("timeoutJobDetail");
        jobDetailFactoryBean.setDescription("Job for timeout");
        jobDetailFactoryBean.setDurability(false);

        Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<String, Long>();
        map.put("contractId", contract.getContractId());
        map.put("userId", user.getUserId());

        jobDetailFactoryBean.setJobDataAsMap(map);
        jobDetailFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        JobDetail jobDetail = jobDetailFactoryBean.getObject();
```

then i create the trigger and pass both to the scheduler

```
SimpleTriggerFactoryBean trigger = new SimpleTriggerFactoryBean();
                trigger.setName("checkContract" + contract.getContractId());
                trigger.setGroup("contractTriggers");
                trigger.setJobDetail(jobDetail);

                trigger.setStartTime(new Date());

                trigger.setRepeatInterval(30 * 24 * 60 * 60 *1000);
                trigger.afterPropertiesSet();
                scheduler.getScheduler().scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger.getObject());
```

When the trigger is created i get this exception

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Repeat interval must be >= 0]
```

pointing at `trigger.setRepeatInterval(30 * 24 * 60 * 60 *1000);`

i really don't know...

Answer (score 1):

**30 * 24 * 60 * 60 *1000** overflows integer limit. Which is why you are seeing that error. Try doing something like below where you convert result to long

```
trigger.setRepeatInterval(30L * 24 * 60 * 60 *1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

To build your interval builder try using the `CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder`

example:

```
public Trigger get30DayTrigger(TriggerKey triggerKey, Date startTime) {
  CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder intervalBuilder = CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder
        .calendarIntervalSchedule()
        .withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing();

  intervalBuilder.withIntervalInDays(30);

  TriggerBuilder<?> triggerBuilder = TriggerBuilder
        .newTrigger()
        .withIdentity(triggerKey)
        .withSchedule(intervalBuilder);

  if (startTime != null) {
    triggerBuilder.startAt(startTime);
  }

  return triggerBuilder.build()
}
```

Then you can do something like

```
TriggerKey key = new TriggerKey("checkContract" + contract.getContractId(), "contractTriggers");
Trigger trigger = get30DayTrigger(key, new Date());

scheduler.getScheduler().scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```